# Retrieving data from Database into an ArrayList

Tags: android

I am trying to store data into arraylist and retrieve it in another activity. I am able to get data from database but not able to retrieve it .I am getting the path name instead of the result i have posted my logcat below kindly give me any suggestion on how to get it done

DBhelper class:

```
public ArrayList<LocationHelper> getAlllocations()
{
    ArrayList<LocationHelper> array_list = new ArrayList<LocationHelper>();

    //hp = new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c =  db.rawQuery( "select * from "+ TABLE_LOCATION, null );
    c.moveToFirst();

    while(c.isAfterLast() == false){
        LocationHelper locationHelper = new LocationHelper();
        locationHelper.setNum(c.getString(1));

        locationHelper.setPresent_lat(c.getString(4));
        Log.e("Database lat: ", locationHelper.getPresent_lat());

        locationHelper.setPresent_lon(c.getString(5));
        Log.e("Database lon: ", locationHelper.getPresent_lon());

        array_list.add(locationHelper);
        Log.e("Database Data: ", String.valueOf(array_list.get(i)));

        c.moveToNext();
        i++;
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

LocationHelper:

```
public class LocationHelper {
String num;

public String getNative_lat() {
    return native_lat;
}

public void setNative_lat(String native_lat) {
    this.native_lat = native_lat;
}

public String getNative_lon() {
    return native_lon;
}

public void setNative_lon(String native_lon) {
    this.native_lon = native_lon;
}

public String getPresent_lat() {
    return present_lat;
}

public void setPresent_lat(String present_lat) {
    this.present_lat = present_lat;
}

public String getPresent_lon() {
    return Present_lon;
}

public void setPresent_lon(String present_lon) {
    Present_lon = present_lon;
}

public String getNum() {
    return num;
}

public void setNum(String num) {
    this.num = num;
}

String native_lat;
String  native_lon;
String present_lat;
String Present_lon;
}
```

Logcat:

```
08-21 15:28:51.364  25317-25317/? E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>>  
com.example.xxx.xxx[ userId:0 | appId:10309 ]
08-21 15:28:51.684  25317-25317/? E/Database lat:﹕ 9.08613
08-21 15:28:51.684  25317-25317/? E/Database lon:﹕ 76.4888
08-21 15:28:51.684  25317-25317/? E/Database Data:﹕ 
com.example.xxx.xxx.LocationHelper@4215d348
08-21 15:28:51.684  25317-25317/? E/Database lat:﹕ 9.08613
08-21 15:28:51.684  25317-25317/? E/Database lon:﹕ 76.9888
08-21 15:28:51.684  25317-25317/? E/Database Data:﹕ 
com.example.xxx.xxx.LocationHelper@4215d868
08-21 15:28:51.684  25317-25317/? E/Database lat:﹕ 9.58613
08-21 15:28:51.684  25317-25317/? E/Database lon:﹕ 76.4888
08-21 15:28:51.684  25317-25317/? E/Database Data:﹕  
com.example.xxx.xxx.LocationHelper@4215db50
08-21 15:28:51.684  25317-25317/? E/Database lat:﹕ 9.58613
08-21 15:28:51.684  25317-25317/? E/Database lon:﹕ 76.9888
08-21 15:28:51.684  25317-25317/? E/Database Data:﹕   
com.example.xxx.xxx.LocationHelper@4215de38
```

Comment: It is not a path. It's an object of ArrayList. You are getting lat and lon then what you want to do?

Comment: i Just want to know how to access the lat and lon from arraylist in another activity

Comment: I don't see you doing anything wrong nor can understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: post your LocationHelper class

Comment: why dont you just retrieve the `ArrayList` in the desired activity

Comment: Just use this method in the `Activity` that you want to use the 'LocationHelper` in

Comment: @Nikhil In your locationhelper object, you have stored both lat and lon values. So when you try to iterate or print the values one by one then you should specify the item which you want. Otherwise it cannot be understandable and it prints the object

Comment: ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAlllocations();
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);                                   can anyone telll me what to do after that to get the lat and lon \

Comment: Here is a good tutorial to get you started if you've never used this before
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#arrayAdapter. In the `ArrayAdapter`'s getView you can get the `ListItem` and display its values as you see fit

Comment: I would also suggest that you use the `ViewHolder` pattern as in here http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Log.e("Database Data: ", String.valueOf(array_list.get(i).getPresent_lat()));
```

or

```
Log.e("Database Data: ", String.valueOf(array_list.get(i).getPresent_lon()));
```

instead of

```
Log.e("Database Data: ", String.valueOf(array_list.get(i)));
```

You are trying to print arraylist object not values.

**EDIT:**

In first activity pass arraylist through Intent

```
intent.putExtra("array_list", array_list);
```

then in second activity get arraylist like this.

```
ArrayList<LocationHelper> myList = (ArrayList<LocationHelper>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("array_list");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you rajeev its working for me but can you tell me how to access the same from diff activity

Answer (score 1):

As @gmetax said it the hashcode which is getting printed. Your `ArrayList` is getting populated exactly as you want. You need to pass that list to another activity using an `Intent` (for eg: intent.addExtras(list)) and iterate the list in another activity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Activity

```
ArrayList<LocationHelper> locatioHelper = new ArrayList<LocationHelper>();
LocationHelper locHelper = new LocationHelper();
DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
locationHelper=db.getAlllocations();
for(int i=0;i<locationHelper.size();i++)
{
  Log.i("latvalue",locHelper.get(i).getPresent_lat());
  Log.i("lonvalue",locHelper.get(i).getgetPresent_lon());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you haven't override the toString method, you are retrieving the content from db fine.

the default toString method from the object class returns

> package.Class@Hashcode

add to your LocationHelper class that code

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "lat : " + getPresent_lat() + ", lon : " + getPresent_lon();
}
```

Comment: go override to get what you want and you are gonna be ok

Comment: It's not what @Nikhil wants. His question is so vague.

Comment: normally arraylist.get(i) gives you what data is present in that array at that postion but in my case i am getting my file path instead of values that i saved into it. i think there is something wrong with my code but not able to find it

Comment: YOU DON'T HAVE toString method on your class, so it returns package.Class@Hashcode as "string output" do you even read my answer? do you even try anything?